# Can I ask for recommendations of further reading?

Tags: discussion, support

I am a 16 year-old learning computing in school. It is something I'd love to pursue, both academically and as a career.

I was wondering if it would be appropriate for me to ask on this site for suggestions of subscription magazines that would help deepen my knowledge of the latest innovations in computer science, and just broaden my understanding of the subject as a whole.

Would this be an on-topic question?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and to the world of computer science! I hope you'll enjoy both.

Comment: Without prior knowledge of about the equivalent of what you would learn in a bachelors course of studies, I don't think cutting-edge research papers will be very useful to you. I recommend you start with the basics, either using textbooks or MOOCs.

Comment: @Raphael maybe in my post I made it sound like I am very new to cs, but I feel I already understand the basics pretty well. I am really looking to further my knowledge of computer science on a level significantly above 'beginner,' I felt that reading about current research etc. might have been useful to do this.

Comment: In that case, browse [cs.SE] and answer some questions. :) You'll find what you need to know pretty quickly, and can then go from there. Frontloading on articles is of limited use, imho.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your goal then it seems not a good fit here. We do not do the books/magazines recommendations here, the same with questions about the current innovations.

Some questions about the current state-of-the-art algorithms for particular problem might be a good fit here (it really depends on the question), but any kind of enumeration of the current algorithms is just to broad.

I wish you luck!

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is not fit for this community, I would like to go ahead and suggest some websites that may help you. I appreciate your interest in Computers and your enthusiastic approach.

You might want to look into the following:

1. Learn some of the basic concepts of programming like OOPs, etc.
2. Implement those concepts using a programming/scripting language. Use online free/paid resources to learn any programming language. Python is used extensively by developers. Java is very popular in academia.
3. Pick an sub-field based on your interest and your level of comfort when reading about that field. Some of the hot areas are Cloud-Computing, Artificial Intelligence, Machine-Learning, Robotics.
4. Take up small projects and use those projects to understand and improve your skills as a programmer.
5. If you feel comfortable, you might want to look into some online programming competition websites. Read the blogs on their website. [***Note***: You may not be able to solve the questions immediately, but that is absolutely fine. The idea is to expose yourself to the different concept and ideas in CS]

**Reference Links:**

Use this [link](https://harshdeepsokhey.wordpress.com/2017/01/14/resources-that-i-use/) to check some of the resources that I mentioned above.

All the Best!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really help me. I am already a very strong programmer and am more interested now in improving myself in the theoretical side of the field rather than programming itself.